# Return field of column in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this table, and I want to filter some fields of it. The table looks like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce7db93db1ec10d08941d44"),
    "name" : "john",
    "age" : "22",
    "group" : "A",
    "nodes" : [ 
        {
            "name1" : "some_name1",
            "status" : "completed"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce7e2fd726ed9434c32aaba"),
    "name" : "mike",
    "age" : "23",
    "group" : "B",
    "nodes" : [ 
        {
            "dev_name" : "some_name_dev1",
            "status" : "not completed"
        }, 
        {
            "dev_name" : "some_name_dev2",
            "status" : "completed"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce7e36c726ed9434c32aabc"),
    "name" : "anne",
    "age" : "24",
    "group" : "C",
    "status" : "pending"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce7f05e726ed9434c32aabe"),
    "name" : "jane",
    "age" : "27",
    "group" : "D",
    "nodes" : [ 
        {
            "dev_name" : "some_name_dev6",
            "status" : "not completed"
        }, 
        {
            "dev_name" : "some_name_dev7"
        }
    ]
}
```

**And what I actually want to return is this** (a simple object with "status" if `nodes` does not exist, and an array if `nodes` exists:

```
/* 1 */
[{
    "status" : "completed"
}]

/* 2 */
[{
    "status" : "not completed"
},
{
     "status" : "completed"
}]

/* 3 */
{
    "status" : "pending"
}

/* 4 */
[{
    "status" : "not completed"
}]
```

I did this:

```
db.getCollection('user').find( 
    { 
        $or: [
                {
                    "status": { $ne:null } 
                },  
                {
                    "nodes.status":{ $exists: true }
                } 
              ] 
     },  
     { 
         'status': 1, 
         'nodes.status': 1,
         '_id': 0
     } 
)
```

and the result is this, and I am a little bit stuck:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "nodes" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "completed"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "nodes" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "not completed"
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "completed"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "status" : "pending"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "nodes" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "not completed"
        }, 
        {}
    ]
}
```

How can I obtain what I want (getting rid of `nodes` field)? Thank you for your time!

EDIT:

```
db.getCollection('user').find( 
    { 
        $or: [
                {
                    "status": { $ne:null } 
                },  
                {
                    "nodes.status":{ $exists: true }
                } 
              ] 
     },  
     { 
         'status': 1, 
         'nodes.status': 1,
         '_id': 0
     },
     [ { "$project": { "status": { "$ifNull" : ["$nodes.status", ""] } } } ]
)
```

Comment: you may use `$project` to get rid off unwanted fields.  ex: `"$project" : {
                "status" : {
                    "$ifNull" : [
                        "$nodes.status", 
                        "if status is null put here whatever you like"
                    ]
                }`

Comment: @YusufArapoglu I did what you suggested, and I obtain the same result (check the `EDIT`)

Comment: Well you do not have to use $ifNull as that was for an example. Just project the field you want to be passed to the next stage.
`"$project" :  { "status" : "$nodes.status"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to the right direction using `{$project: <expression>}` to change the format of your return document. But I don't think the `$ifNull` has been used correctly. According to the doc, the input of the `$ifNull` is

```
{ $ifNull: [ <expression>, <replacement-expression-if-null> ] }
```

Full Query:

```
db.getCollection('user').find( 
{ 
    $or: [
            {
                "status": { $ne:null } 
            },  
            {
                "nodes.status":{ $exists: true }
            } 
          ] 
 },  
 { 
     'status': { "$ifNull" : ["$status", "$nodes.status"] },  
     '_id': 0
 })
```

**Edit**: Using aggregation instead of simple find(), as $ifNull operator is only available using aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([


{
    $match: {  #behaves like the find operator
      $or: [
        {
          "status": {
            $ne: null
          }
        },
        {
          "nodes.status": {
            $exists: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "status": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$status",
          "$nodes.status"
        ]
      },
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

**output:**

```
[
  {
    "status": [
      "completed"
    ]
  },
  {
    "status": [
      "not completed",
      "completed"
    ]
  },
  {
    "status": "pending"
  },
  {
    "status": [
      "not completed"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: `"errmsg" : "Unsupported projection option: status: { $ifNull: [ \"$status\", \"$nodes.status\" ] }",`

Comment: I am glad to be of help :)